# Does the notification get deleted when comment is editted?

Tags: discussion, comments, notifications

When a user writes a comment to reply to another user using @username then this user gets a notification. However, what happen if after few seconds the commenter edits his comment and deletes @username or changes the reply to another user. Does the notification sent to the user get deleted if he hasn't read it yet?

Comment: I think the dup applies because the answer will fit here as well. The question oth is the opposite of yours